Can recharts draw lines of data at different frequencies?
I am currently pulling my hair around a problem that sounds simple at first: I have data at different frequencies (e.g. 1 point every 15minutes for one series, and 1 every 1hour for another) that I want to plot on the same chart, but can't seem to get the result I expect. I either get no line display for the daily data (as missing points are treated as missing using a single data set), or cannot get the tooltip to display data properly (if I set the data manually on the line), as the arrays do not have the same lengths.
Additionally, I need to synchronize the tooltip across muliple trends (at either same or different frequencies)...
I already fiddled with:

trying to fill the missing data with null or undefined, but that leads to no line being shown
using array of data per line instead of global data array and dataKey, but that leads to out-of-sync tooltip and active dots
to fix the above, set allowDuplicatedCategory={false}, which synchronizes the tooltip and the active dot, but does not shown anything in the tooltip

Any way to reconcile all this, or am I pushing the library to its bounds?
